# Модуль авторизации на php

Tags: php, инспекция-кода

Не подскажете надежный модуль авторизации для сайта, логин и пароль хранятся в БД? Я сейчас использую вот такой модуль, посмотрите, пожалуйста, как он в плане безопасности?

```
<?
$user_status = '0'; // обнуляем статус пользователя, 0 - пользователь не авторизован


if (isset ($_COOKIE['Login']) || isset ($_COOKIE['Password'])) {
    $_COOKIE['Login']    = htmlspecialchars ($_COOKIE['Login']);
    $_COOKIE['Password'] = htmlspecialchars ($_COOKIE['Password']);
}


// читаем куки и смотрим, есть ли в базе пользователь с таким паролем, 
// и проверяем были ли нажаты кнопки вход или выход
if (isset ($_COOKIE['Login']) && 
    isset ($_COOKIE['Password']) && 
    empty ($_POST['auth']) && 
    empty ($_GET['exit'])) {

    // запрос
    $sql = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "_users` 
         WHERE `login` = '" . $_COOKIE['Login'] . "' 
         && `password` = '" . $_COOKIE['Password'] . "'");

    // если есть совпадение, авторизуем пользователя
    if (mysql_num_rows ($sql) > 0) {

        // собираем все данные о пользователе в массив
        $userinfo = mysql_fetch_array ($sql); 

        // устанавливаем куки
        SetCookie ("Login",    mysql_real_escape_string($userinfo['login']));
        SetCookie ("Password", mysql_real_escape_string($userinfo['password']));

        $user_status = '1'; // статус пользователя, 1 - авторизован админ
    }
}


// если была нажата кнопка из формы авторизации
if ($_POST['auth']) { 

    // ищем совпадение пары логин-пароль в таблице
    $auth = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "_users` 
          WHERE `login` = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['login']). "' 
          && `password` = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST ['pass']) . "'");

    // если есть совпадение, авторизуем пользователя
    if (mysql_num_rows($auth) > '0'){

        // собираем все данные о пользователе в массив
        $userinfo = mysql_fetch_array ($auth);

        // устанавливаем куки
        SetCookie ('Login',    mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['login']));
        SetCookie ('Password', mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']));

        $user_status = '1'; // статус пользователя, 1 - авторизован админ
    } else { // если если пара логин-пароль не совпала, выводим сообщение об ошибке
        echo "Такой пользователь не существует или пароль не верный.";
    }
}


// если нажата кнопка выход
if ($_GET['exit']) { 

    // удаляем куки
    SetCookie ('Login',    mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['login']));
    SetCookie ('Password', mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']));
}

// если статус пользователя не изменился, выводим форму авторизации 
if ($user_status == '0') {

//include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/admin/inc/header.php'; // шапка админки
?>
    <!-- форма авторизации -->
    <div style="position:absolute;width:260px;left:50%;top:50%;
    margin-left:-150px;margin-top:-100px;background:#777;color:#eee;
    border:solid 1px black;padding:10px;
    font-family:Tahoma,Arial,FreeSans,Garuda,Utkal,sans-serif;overflow:auto">
        <form method="post" action="index.php">
            Логин:<br>
            <input type="text" name="login" style="width:250px">
            <br><br>
            Пароль:<br>
            <input type="password" name="pass" style="width:250px">
            <br><br>
            <input type="submit" name="auth" value="Войти">
        </form>
    </div>
<?
}
?>
```

Comment: Пароль в куках - отказать.

Comment: т.е. нельзя хранить пароль в куках?

Comment: Конечно же нет. Его и в базе хранить нельзя. Единственное место, где должен мелькать пароль - передача из формы авторизации. Причём только методом POST (чтобы в логах веб-сервера не светился).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Бр... товарищи, обучитесь всёже грамотности:

В первую очередь, система безопасности идентифицирует пользователя, запрашивая у него ту или иную информацию. Этот процесс называется **аутентификацией** и означает, что система пытается понять, кто вы есть такой.

После того как система идентифицирует вас, следующим шагом требуется определить, имеете ли вы права на доступ к затребованному ресурсу. Эта часть процесса называется **авторизацией** и подразумевает проверку ваших привилегий на выполнение того или иного действия.

Answer (score 2):

[Ну вот так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search/?q=%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F+php&t=question)

Answer (score 0):

Авторизация делается ручками за 5 минут без всяких модулей.. форма, скрипт обработчик и сессия... авторизационные данные хранятся в любом удобном вам виде..

Comment: Я просто боюсь возможных уязвимостей написанного мною модуля.

Comment: Волков бояться - в лес не ходить (с)